# Array.Some must contain at least one populated value

Tags: javascript

S I am practicing something with array.prototype.some()

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Basically what I am trying to do is as long as an array contains a populated  string value and some empty string values. I want it to be true as long as one populated string value is in the array for example.

```
const array1 = [ 'g', '']; //returns true
const array2 = [ '', '']; //return true
const array3 = [ '', 'x']; //return true
const array4 = [ 'g', 'x']; //return false
// checks whether an element contains at least one populated string (non blank string)
const even = (element) => element === '';

console.log(array1.some(even)); //Should be True
console.log(array2.some(even)); //Should be False
console.log(array3.some(even)); //Should be True
console.log(array4.some(even)); //Should be True
```

I know its because the element === '' but i don;t know what to write to make it the way i want it, thanks in advance!

Comment: Why is the function named `even`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invert the test - check that some elements are *not* the empty string:

```js
const array1 = [ 'g', '']; //returns true
const array2 = [ '', '']; //return true
const array3 = [ '', 'x']; //return true
const array4 = [ 'g', 'x']; //return false
// checks whether an element contains at least one populated string (non blank string)
const even = (element) => element !== '';

console.log(array1.some(even)); //Should be True
console.log(array2.some(even)); //Should be False
console.log(array3.some(even)); //Should be True
console.log(array4.some(even)); //Should be True
```